# c# how can save create control in run time on windows form application?

Tags: c#

How to save Position and Properties after user click save_button. then UI show, so that UI show every time on application start.
My Code create button and moving...

```
private Point firstpoint = new Point();

private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string bttext = txt_tbname.Text;
    int w, h;
    int cw, ch;
    if (txt_tbname.Text == "" || txt_width.Text == "" || txt_height.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please insert Name, Width and Height before submit", "Informations", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        List<Button> button = new List<Button>();
        Button newbtn = new Button();
        w = Convert.ToInt32(txt_width.Text);
        h = Convert.ToInt32(txt_height.Text); 
        cw = w * 80;
        ch = h * 80;
        newbtn.Width = cw;
        newbtn.Height = ch;
        button.Add(newbtn);
        this.Controls.Add(newbtn);
        newbtn.Text = "" + bttext;
        newbtn.BackColor = Color.MediumPurple;
        newbtn.ForeColor = Color.White;

        newbtn.MouseDown += (ss, ee) =>
          {
              if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
              {
                  firstpoint = Control.MousePosition;
              }
          };
        newbtn.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point temp = Control.MousePosition;
                Point res = new Point(firstpoint.X - temp.X, firstpoint.Y - temp.Y);
                newbtn.Location = new Point(newbtn.Location.X - res.X, newbtn.Location.Y - res.Y);
                firstpoint = temp;
            }
        };
        cleartxt();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could save Position and Properties to a file or DataBase ,when User click the button.
Restart the application reload the data

Comment: Yes. this programs need to do. How do i can.

Comment: Did you have any experience on save data to database or file?

Comment: That’s insert data to database. If text I can, but is control.I not understand of type to save.

Comment: You could save the moving data,when user click the button.